# Different behavior calling JMP with register vs value

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler, intel-syntax

I'm trying to perform an absolute jump to the address 0x7C00 as part of a procedure in a hobby OS. I'm using intel syntax in GAS and testing in QEMU. I tried two methods:

```
jmp 0x00007c00
```

and

```
mov eax, 0x00007C00
jmp eax
```

The second method seems to work as I intended and jumps to 0x7C00, but the first method causes QEMU to crash stating that it's "trying to execute code outside RAM or ROM at 0x40007c00". Does anyone know why it's jumping to a different address and the upper bytes are being set to 0x4000?

EDIT:

When dissassembling, I've received the following respectively:

```
  3c:   e9 fc 7b 00 00          jmp    7c3d <int32_end+0x7ad4>
```

and

```
  3c:   b8 00 7c 00 00          mov    $0x7c00,%eax
  41:   ff e0                   jmp    *%eax
```

So they are compiling differently, although I'm still a bit confused on what exactly the second one is doing which looks like a jump to 0x7c3d

Comment: Look at the resulting machine code (e.g. by disassembling).  `jmp 0x00007c00` assembles to a `jmp rel16` to that absolute target address, assuming some current address set by the linker.  Use a disassembler to see what machine code you got.

Comment: That disassembly shows you assembled for 32-bit mode.  Are you sure that makes sense for jumping to `0x7c00`, which is where a 16-bit MBR boot sector gets loaded, and runs in 16-bit real mode?  Does your bootloader overwrite that memory with 32-bit machine code before jumping back to there?

Comment: The code is actually part of a switch to and from realmode (to perform a bios interrupt). That particular jump is before entering realmode. It works by copying some 16-bit code into the lower 16 bit address space at 0x7C00 and then jumping to that.

Comment: The code should be free to be overwritten as this is after GRUB has handed off control.

Comment: Ok, that's fine if you do it right; I thought you might be building a 16-bit MBR boot sector incorrectly.  But if you have 16-bit code at `0x7c00`, you need to jump there with a far jump to a 16-bit code segment, or you have to have left protected mode already.  A direct near `jmp rel32` to 16-bit code from 32-bit code doesn't make sense.

Comment: Sorry, the code copied at `0x7c00` actually has 32-bit code at the very beginning, and then changes to 16-bit. So are you saying that `jmp    7c3d` is attempting to perform a relative jump?

Comment: Ok, that's sane after all.  But yes, all x86 direct near jumps are relative. https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/jmp shows the encoding for the E9 opcode your `jmp` is using.  To encode the right `rel32` offset to reach a given absolute target address, the assembler + linker need to know the address where the jump instruction will be running from.  If you want your code doing the jump to be position-independent, the best approach is mov-immediate + `jmp eax`.

Comment: @23scurtu: Don't forget that there's no guarantee that the BIOS exists (and no guarantee that the firmware isn't UEFI or something else); and therefore no guarantee that what you're doing (switching back to real mode to cause the computer to crash) isn't a massive design failure.

Comment: @PeterCordes Why is the relative offset `7c3d` so small then?  This code uses addresses in the higher half of memory since I've configured it to start at 0xC0100000 in the linker (but be loaded starting at 0x00100000). Knowing that relative offsets are calculated based on where the jump will be running from explains why I see so many 0x40000000 in the dissassembled code (Adding 0x40000000 to 0xC0000000 puts the address in 0x00000000), but I don't see why this offset is so small...

Comment: The disassembler is calculating the absolute address for your convenience, based on the address it's showing for the end of that instruction.  The actual relative displacement is the little-endian `fc 7b 00 00` = `0x00007bfc`.  If you're disassembling a `.o`, the linker hasn't filled in the real displacement yet; use `objdump -drwC -Mintel`.

Comment: @Brendan Currently I'm using GRUB for i386 which from my understanding is for BIOS and not UEFI, does this not allow me to guarantee the BIOS exists?

Comment: @PeterCordes Ah okay, I think this all makes sense now. So in general when typing `jmp 0x00007c00` I'm not actually asking it to go to address 0x7c00 but instead saying to jump ahead by 0x7c00. Whatever number is supplied after jmp is a relative offset and I should be using mov-immediate + jmp eax instead if I want an absolute jump.

Comment: Furthermore, I think my confusion about why the addresses are so small is because I failed to realize that addresses in .o files are realtive to the start of the file, hence why it resides at `3c` which is its offset in the file. If I dissassemble the final elf file made after linking all of the addresses have 0xC0100000 added to them as I expected.

Comment: `jmp 0x00007c00` in the source *does* give it that absolute jump target, but the assembler will reach it with a relative jump.  It's not the same as `jmp .+0x7c00` or specifying the rel32 displacement directly.  You can see this more easily if you repeat the instruction twice in a file by itself and assemble+link it into an ELF executable (e.g. `gcc -static -nostdlib foo.s` && `objdump -drwC -Mintel a.out`). You'll see two jmp instructions with different encodings (different rel32) and the same absolute target.

Comment: @23scurtu: For the purpose of future-proofing, I doubt "currently" is very relevant (especially when it's something like "currently dependent on BIOS, GRUB 1 and multi-boot 1; which were all deprecated about 10 years ago").

Comment: @PeterCordes Okay I can see the assembler reaching 0x7C00 with a relative jump (of 0x3ff06723) in the final elf, makes sense. I think your comments that I upvoted answer my original question pretty well, should an answer be formulated for this or is it fine left as a comment chain?

Comment: If you want to summarize them into an answer, feel free.  I'm pretty sure I've written answers about `objdump -d` on `.o` files, and how it disassembles relative jumps, on some other question, so alternatively you could go look for a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer turned out to be a series of insights gone over in the comments:

First was dissassembling the code to see that the jmp assembled into a near `jmp rel32`. As it turns out, all x86 direct near jumps are relative. [felixcloutier.com/x86/jmp](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/jmp) shows the encoding for the E9 opcode this jmp is using. To encode the right rel32 offset to reach a given absolute target address, the assembler + linker need to know the address where the jump instruction will be running from.

`jmp 0x00007c00` in the source gives it the absolute jump target of `0x00007c00`, but the assembler will reach it with a relative jump. It's not the same as `jmp .+0x7c00` or specifying the rel32 displacement directly. This can be seen easily if the instruction is written twice in a file by itself and its assembled+linked into an ELF executable (e.g. `gcc -static -nostdlib foo.s && objdump -drwC -Mintel a.out`). Here the two jmp instructions have different encodings (different rel32) and the same absolute target. Additionally, when observing the final elf you can see the assembler reaching `0x7C00` with a relative jump (of `0x3ff06723` since the code addresses begin at `0xC0100000`).

One issue I had was that the addresses and jumps seem far too small when my code is supposed to begin at `0xC0100000`. I failed to realize that addresses in .o files are relative to the start of the file, hence why the instruction resides at `0x3c` which is its offset in the file. If I dissassemble the final elf file made after linking, all of the addresses have `0xC0100000` added to them.

Also worth noting is that the disassembler is calculating the absolute address `7c3d` for convenience, based on the address it's showing for the end of that instruction. The actual relative displacement is the little-endian `fc 7b 00 00 = 0x00007bfc`. Since I was disassembling a .o file, the linker hadn't filled in the real displacement yet. This can be avoided by using `objdump -drwC -Mintel.`

In order to make the code doing the jump to be position-independent, the best approach is sticking with the `mov-immediate` + `jmp eax` used in the second method.